# Getting inactive users from database

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have SQL database dump from some forum. I'm trying to build query which will return me a list of unactive users that didn't send any post from like one year. I'm thinking about using subquery with last post but i'm not sure if i'm right. For now I didn't manage to get any possible results... Can you help me guys?

post_database:

```
id  INTEGER                         
topic_id    INTEGER                         
post_id INTEGER                         
user_id INTEGER                         
date    TEXT                            
content TEXT
```

user_database:

```
id  INTEGER                         
name    TEXT
```

Comment: Why is your date stored as `TEXT`?

Comment: I'm using SQLite which uses TEXT also for storing dates.

Comment: Why do you have `mysql` label instead of `sqlite`?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about SQLite, but you want to `GROUP BY` some fields and use a `HAVING` clause to limit to those who haven't posted in the past year:

```
SELECT u.name
FROM post_database AS p
JOIN user_database AS u
  ON p.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.name
HAVING MAX(date) < DATE('now','-1 year')
```

I'm not sure about the date comparison portion.

Comment: This won't find users who've never posted at all.

Comment: @hvd True enough, but didn't see that in the scope of the question.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! I was trying similar thing once but without "HAVING" and i was recieving bad results, now it works as expected!

Comment: @GoatCO The question asks for "users that didn't send any post from like one year", and users who've never posted at all certainly *seem* to qualify to me. :)

Comment: @hvd Agreed, if they exist, they would qualify.